# Classification algorithm - decision tree

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, decision-tree

I have MPU6050 accelerometer data collected from an induction motor. I wanted to train an algorithm and make the predictions using new dataset.

I have trained the algorithm using decision tree classifier and got the 100% score and also did testing

When I try to give new dataset to this model, the classification is not done correctly.I have given an example at the end of the code.

Please find the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy
import pickle
from pandas.tools.plotting import scatter_matrix
from matplotlib import cm

filename=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Meena/Desktop/Datawithlabel.txt", sep=',')
filename.columns = ["x", "y", "z","Label"]

feature_names=['x']
X=filename[feature_names]
y=filename['Label']


from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=7)

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()

X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)


from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier().fit(X_train, y_train)


print('Accuracy of Decision Tree classifier on training set: {:.2f}'
     .format(clf.score(X_train, y_train)))
```

> Accuracy of Decision Tree classifier on training set: 1.00

```
Filename='final_model.sav'
pickle.dump(clf,open(Filename,'wb'))
load_model=pickle.load(open(Filename,'rb'))
result=load_model.score(X_test,y_test)
print(result)
```

> 0.9393939393939394

```
load_model=pickle.load(open(Filename,'rb'))

filename1=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Meena/Desktop/Motor2withloadsafter5min.txt", sep=',')
filename1.columns = ["x", "y", "z"]
Datatopredict=filename1[['x']]

prediction = load_model.predict(Datatopredict)

print(prediction)
```

Even though for these values its given as non working class in training set, it still yields as working class in prediction. I am not sure where is it going wrong...

In the below data, first column is index and the second column is the X axis data from the accelerometer

```
590  0.03
591  0.03
592  0.02
593  0.02
594  0.01
595  0.04
596  0.12
597  0.12
598  0.11
599  0.14
```

> ['working' 'working' 'working' 'working' 'working' 'working' 'working'
>    'working' 'working' 'working']

[This is the screenshot of the training data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3Ih9.png)

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you are saying. What do you mean by `"Even though for these values its given as non working class in training set, it still yields as working class in prediction"`? Are the same values being predicted differently. Can you share the training data?

Comment: Training data set is too big thatsy I could not share. But check the new screen shot that I have attached in which the class for the values [596 - 599] are classifies as non working but the result of the prediction classifies them as working

Answer (score 2):

One thing I noticed in addition to my comment above is that you are not scaling the test values.

You need to use the same scaler on X_test as well, like: `X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)` before prediction. So pickle the `scaler` as well and load that during testing.
During training:

```
Filename = 'final_model.sav'
pickle.dump(clf, open(Filename, 'wb'))

scaler_Filename = 'final_scalar.sav'
pickle.dump(scaler, open(scaler_Filename, 'wb'))
```

During testing:

```
load_scaler = pickle.load(open(scaler_Filename,'rb'))
X_test = load_scaler.transform(X_test)

load_model = pickle.load(open(Filename,'rb'))
result = load_model.score(X_test,y_test)

print(result)
```

On new data:

```
Datatopredict = load_scaler.transform(Datatopredict)
prediction = load_model.predict(Datatopredict)
```

Comment: when i try to scale it as u said,I am  getting following error: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-02034e2dc1a2> in <module>()
      3 
      4 load_model = pickle.load(open(Filename,'rb'))
----> 5 result = load_model.score(X_test,y_test)
      6 
      7 print(result)

AttributeError: 'MinMaxScaler' object has no attribute 'score'

Comment: Sill the same [

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-02034e2dc1a2> in <module>()
      3 
      4 load_model = pickle.load(open(Filename,'rb'))
----> 5 result = load_model.score(X_test,y_test)
      6 
      7 print(result)

AttributeError: 'MinMaxScaler' object has no attribute 'score' ]

Comment: @MeenakshiChowdhary Try now please.

Comment: Is there a way that I can print both the new input and its respective predicted class?